# how to do Shell Navigation with complex objects in .net MAUI or Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, maui, .net-maui

Recently I've started using shell and I noticed an improvement in page transitioning and a bug I was facing using NavigationPage was fixed just by replacing it with shell.

So I was excited to use it.

However soon after I realized I can't send objects from page to page through shell like I could using a constructer of a page. I searched a bit and now know that shell passes strings only. I turned the object into JSON but then faced an exception due to long URI length.

Honestly, I am disappointed. I thought something this important would be implemented in shell... but In any case, how do you guys work around this?

Answer (score 1):

For **Maui**.

See [(Xamarin) Process navigation data using a single method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method).

Also mentioned in [maui issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/4968). Adapting the Maui invocation there:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//myAwesomeUri",
    new Dictionary { {"data", new MyData(...)} });
```

This uses `IQueryAttributable` and `ApplyQueryAttributes` to pass an `IDictionary<string, object> query`.
(The Xamarin example shows `IDictionary<string, string>`, but its `, object` in Maui, so you can pass any object values.)

Thus the string parameters you pass can be used to look up corresponding objects.

From that (Xamarin) doc (modified to show looking up an object):

```cs
public class MonkeyDetailViewModel : IQueryAttributable, ...
{
    public MyData Data { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        Data = (MyData)query["data"];
    }
    ...
}
```

---

For **Xamarin Forms**, the limitation to string values makes this a bit ugly. One approach is to have a `static` that holds possible objects, which you look up using a string. This is tolerable when the objects are all pre-defined, but is a bit clumsy if you are manually altering those objects.

```cs
public class MonkeyDetailViewModel : IQueryAttributable, ...
{
    public static Dictionary<string, MyData> KeyedData;

    // "static": One-time class constructor.
    public static MonkeyDetailViewModel()
    {
        KeyedData = new Dictionary<string, MyData>();
        KeyedData["data1"] = new MyData(...);
        // ... other versions of the data ...
    }


    public MyData Data { get; private set; }

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, string> query)
    {
        string whichData = query["data"];   // In example, gets "data1".
        Data = KeyedData[whichData];
    }
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//myAwesomeUri",
    new Dictionary { {"data", "data1"} });
```

Xamarin NOTE: The static dictionary makes it possible to maintain multiple instances of `MyData`. The "hack" alternative is to have `MyData Data` be `static`, and explicitly set it before `GoToAsync` - but this is risky if you ever might have a MonkeyDetailView on nav stack, go to a second one, then go back to first one - you'll have overwritten the `Data` seen by the first view.